# Adding days to the current utc date in angular

Tags: angular

I am writing a jasmine test where I need to manipulate UTC date. At the moment i am able to get UTC date in the format I want. I have mentioned in my test where i need to pass the added date before it formats it. Its the component.GetUtcDate call

For e.g 2020-03-20T14:24:52.000

I need to add days to date before I pass it to the GetUtcDate method. How do I do that ?. Ultimately say after adding 5 days it should show 2020-03-25T14:24:52.000

```
let todayDate: Date;
let acceptanceDate: Date;
let acceptanceDateUtc: string;


fit('should call checkIfLastAgreement and notify that its the last agreement when  is called accept is called', () => {
    todayDate = new Date();
    acceptanceDate = component.GetUtcDate(NEED TO ADD DAYS TO THE DATE HERE);
    acceptanceDateUtc = acceptanceDate.toISOString();
    acceptanceDateUtc = acceptanceDateUtc.substring( 0,  acceptanceDateUtc.length - 1);
    component.currentIndex = 0;
    component.myData = [{userAgreementId: 1}, { acceptanceWindowExpiry: acceptanceDateUtc }];
    component.agreementLength = 2;
    component.lastAgreement = true;
    component.activeBtn = 0;
    component.accept();

    expect(component.agreementsService.updateAgreement).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(component.lastAgreement).toBe(true);
    expect(component.endOfAgreements).toBe(true);
  });
```

Component code

```
 GetUtcDate(date: Date) {
    const now_utc =  Date.UTC(date.getUTCFullYear(), date.getUTCMonth(), date.getUTCDate(),
    date.getUTCHours(), date.getUTCMinutes(), date.getUTCSeconds());

    return new Date(now_utc);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't really understand what you need but if you want to add days to a Date type you just have to do like this :

```js
const today = new Date();

const fiveNextDays = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate() + 5);
```